# The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "xxx", but the current user is ""

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I've looked through a lot of S.O. pages on this subject but mine is a little different. This has nothing to do with an anti-forgery protected login page or users hitting the back button. At our university we use University of Michigan's CoSign as a single-sign-on solution. Users are authenticated through cosign and on success the username is provided by the IIS server in Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] and can then be used for authorization, etc.

Here's some code: in global.asax.cs:

```
Session["username"] = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"];
```

On each page that might use Ajax (in a file Init.js; code from https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/jswebapps-csrf):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SetCSRFHeader();
}
function SetCSRFHeader() {
var CSRF_HEADER = 'RequestVerificationToken';

var setCSRFToken = function (securityToken) {
    jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, _, xhr) {
        if (!xhr.crossDomain)
            xhr.setRequestHeader(CSRF_HEADER, securityToken);
    });
};
var theTokenVal = $('#__bothTokens').val();
setCSRFToken(theTokenVal);
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@{
string cookieToken, formToken, bothTokens;
AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
bothTokens = cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
}
<input type="hidden" id="__bothTokens" value="@(bothTokens)" />
```

I also wrote a class that implements IHttpModule to check all POST requests for the included header, parse it and validate it (code from https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91164/how-to-check-the-origin-header-server-wide-in-iis-to-prevent-csrf):

```
public class HeaderCheck : IHttpModule
{
     public HeaderCheck()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest +=
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source,
         EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        int errCode = 0;
        int STATCODE = 403;
        string cookieToken = "";
        string formToken = "";
        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST") // only on POST requests
        {
            if (context.Request.Headers["Content-Type"] != null) 
            {
                if (context.Request.Headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json;") // JSON check
                {
                    if (context.Request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
                    {
                        string tokenHeaders = context.Request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"]; 
                        string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.Split(':');
                        if (tokens.Length == 2)
                        {
                            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errCode = 3;
                    }
                }
                else if (context.Request.Headers["Content-Type"].Length >= 19)
                {
                    if (context.Request.Headers["Content-Type"].Substring(0, 19) == "multipart/form-data") // Form check
                    {
                        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("__RequestVerificationToken");
                        cookie = context.Request.Cookies["__RequestVerificationToken"];
                        formToken = context.Request.Form["__RequestVerificationToken"];
                        if (formToken == null) { tokenstr = "form null"; }
                        if (cookie != null)
                        {
                            cookieToken = cookie.Value;
                            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
                        }
                        else // cookie is null
                        {
                            errCode = 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else // neither acceptable content form
                {
                    errCode = 5;
                }
            }
            else // content type should not be null
            {
                errCode = 6;
            }
            if (errCode > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
                }
                catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e2)
                {
                    string err = @"Antiforgery tokens not validated" +
                        "<br><b>Error in: </b>"
                        + context.Request.Url.ToString()
                        + "<br><b>Error Message: </b>"
                        + e2.Message.ToString()
                        + "<br><b>Stack Trace:</b><br>"
                        + e2.StackTrace.ToString();
                    EmailContext.sendEmailOnError(err); // sends email to me for debugging
                }
            }

            if (errCode > 0)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = STATCODE;
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

}
}
```

My questions: Why am I getting the error in the title of this question? How does AntiForgeryValidate know that the token was meant for me but somehow the token that's generated is for current user ""? Is there any way I can put the user into the token? I've even tried the advice at [Reload AntiForgeryToken after a login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815634/reload-antiforgerytoken-after-a-login) to always regenerate the token the first time the user hits the home page (since they're already logged in at that point. Does this have anything to do with developing in visual studio in HTTP but the acceptance environment which is cosign-protected is https? Does it have anything to do with the fact that IIS is configured for Anonymous Authentication? (I think it needs to be to run under cosign).

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: More and more I think this is due to IIS Anonymous Authentication being the only mode that's enabled. But any other mode requires some sort of second login, and since cosign is THE authentication provider, that doesn't help. So if anyone has any idea how to programmatically insert the user credentials received from cosign into IIS that might be the way forward.